# the function, "queue", can it only be executed once?

Tags: jquery, queue, addclass, removeclass

here's my code

```
$('.project, .list').click(function(){
    $( ".c3_home" ).addClass('c3_left2').delay(400).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass('c3_right');
});
});
$('#back').click(function(){
    $('.c3_home').removeClass('c3_right c3_left2');
});
```

on the first two clicks, the classes are added and removed but on the third click, only the c3_left is added while c3_right is not being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the queue:

```
$( ".c3_home" ).clearQueue().addClass('c3_left2').delay(400).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass('c3_right');
});
```

You could try using finish(): (jq 1.9 >) {which is supposed to clear all elements in queue}

```
$( ".c3_home" ).finish().addClass('c3_left2').delay(400).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass('c3_right');
});
```

As suggested by Kevin, try that too:

```
$( ".c3_home" ).addClass('c3_left2').delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass('c3_right');
        next();
    });
```

Comment: I wonder if executing the `next` function passed to the queue callback would fix it too.

Comment: @KevinB it would be more appropriate btw